# Whats the difference in a TVS of common anode vs common cathode?

Tags: diodes, protection, esd, tvs

I found this two TVS diode and there is a difference in the diagram of the diode representation.

[image]

Common Cathode:
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/dm00207446-1798715.pdf

Common Anode:
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/vcan16a2-03g-1713959.pdf

Is there any difference between this two? Or one of them is wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't be any functional difference between the two: the path only conducts when the voltage across it exceeds one forward diode drop plus one zener drop - doesn't matter in which order.

Comment: None of they are bidrectional TVS diodes.

Comment: yes, they are. Both are a two line bidirectional TVS.

Comment: Do you guys think the physical arrangement of the semi-conductors matches the symbols?

Answer (score 2):

According to this Onsemi datasheet:
https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mmbz15vdlt1-d.pdf
Note: the dual common anode zener configuration shown above is electrically equivalent to a dual common
cathode zener configuration